# Adding multiple device tokens for a single userId

Tags: android, ios, django, amazon-web-services, notifications

I am creating a notification server for my app . I want to add multiple device tokens for a single userId. Currently when a user logins from a new device his previous device token is deleted. This way if he is using two devices simultaneously he will get notification in one device only. How can I store multiple device tokens for that particular user so that he gets notification on both of his devices.

Comment: You need to change your database so that you insert an additional row for a new registration rather than replacing the existing row.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's seems like you want to send notification to every device user logged in. So whenever you are inserting the device id to user database you must have to refer user id for particular user and base on it you need to check if the new token is same as existing one then you don't need to do anything else you need to insert the new device token with the reference of user id.